# Plot of normal curve not...normal

Tags: python, matplotlib, normal-distribution

I am plotting both a distribution of test scores and a fitted curve to these test scores:

```
h = sorted(data['Baseline'])  #sorted
fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))
plt.plot(h,fit,'-o')
plt.hist(h,normed=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
plt.show()
```

The plot of the pdf, however, does not look normal (see kink in curve near x=60).   See output:

[image]

I'm not sure what is going on here...any help appreciated.  Is this because the normal line is being drawn between supplied observations?    Can provide you with the actual data if needed, there are only 60 observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you evaluate the norm-pdf on the overservation. You would instead want to create some other data like

```
h = sorted(data['Baseline'])  #sorted
x = np.linspace(h.min(), h.max(), 151)

fit = stats.norm.pdf(x, np.mean(h), np.std(h))

plt.plot(x,fit,'-')
plt.hist(h,normed=True) 
plt.show()
```

Note however, that the data does not look normally distributed at all. So potentially you would rather fit a different distribution, or maybe perform a kernel density estimate.

Comment: Looks more like lognormal Distribution

Comment: Yes, agree. My question was more about the fit and plt.plot() - turns out I wasn't creating an X vector with equally spaced intervals, but relying on the sorted data to determine X.  Thanks.

Comment: But @Basingaa, your point makes sense:   as the values cannot be lower than 0, that almost guarantees a lognormal distribution.

Comment: "almost guarantees"??? One should be very careful to assume a certain distribution by looking at the data alone. The strategy should always be to build a model first, based on the origin of the data. Then verify the model by fitting the expected distribution.